# IllegalAnnotationException when moving from Oracle 10g to Weblogic (10.3.6)

Tags: java, oracle, maven

We're moving a web application from Oracle 10g OC4J to Weblogic 10.3.6 and we're stuck on the following IllegalAnnotationException:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userService': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ServiceConstructionException
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1420)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
..........
Caused by: com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException: 4 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions
Class has two properties of the same name "arg0"
this problem is related to the following location:
    at public java.lang.String com.xyz.service.jaxws_asm.GetUserByUsername.getArg0()
    at com.xyz.service.jaxws_asm.GetUserByUsername
this problem is related to the following location:
    at private java.lang.String com.xyz.service.jaxws_asm.GetUserByUsername.arg0
    at com.xyz.service.jaxws_asm.GetUserByUsername
Class has two properties of the same name "arg0".....
```

UserService class:

```
import com.xyz.model.AppUser;
import javax.jws.WebService;
import javax.ws.rs.DELETE;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import java.util.List;

/**
* Web Service interface so hierarchy of Generic Manager isn't carried   through.
*/
@WebService
@Path("/")
@Produces({"application/json", "application/xml"})

public interface UserService {

@GET
@Path("/user/{id}")
AppUser getUser(@PathParam("id") String userId);

AppUser getUserByUsername(@PathParam("username") String username);

@GET
@Path("/users")
List<AppUser> getUsers();

@POST
@Path("/user")
AppUser saveUser(AppUser user) throws UserExistsException;

@DELETE
@Path("/user")
void removeUser(String userId);
}
```

Looking at other problems similar to this, we're wondering if it has something to do with javax.xml.bind but so far we haven't found the right solution. Just in case it is, here's the relevant dependency from the pom:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
  <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
  <version>2.2</version>
  <scope>compile</scope>
  <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
      <artifactId>stax-api</artifactId>
      <groupId>stax</groupId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Posting dependency tree as we're still looking into the issue. Possible issue with dependencies, Java 6, and Weblogic 10.3.5?

```
[INFO] [dependency:tree {execution: default-cli}]
[INFO] com.xyz:proj_1:war:1.0
[INFO] +- com.oracle:oracle:jar:11.2.0.3.0:compile
[INFO] +- commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:jar:1.8.3:compile
[INFO] |  \- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.1:compile
[INFO] +- commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.2.1:compile
[INFO] +- commons-dbcp:commons-dbcp:jar:1.3:compile
[INFO] |  \- commons-pool:commons-pool:jar:1.5.4:compile
[INFO] +- commons-fileupload:commons-fileupload:jar:1.2.1:compile
[INFO] +- commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.6:compile
[INFO] +- commons-el:commons-el:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] +- displaytag:displaytag:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.lowagie:itext:jar:1.3:compile
[INFO] +- javax.mail:mail:jar:1.4.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- javax.activation:activation:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] +- javax.servlet:servlet-api:jar:2.4:provided
[INFO] +- javax.servlet:jstl:jar:1.1.2:compile
[INFO] +- javax.servlet.jsp:jsp-api:jar:2.0:provided
[INFO] +- javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:jar:2.2.12:compile
[INFO] +- log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.16:compile
[INFO] +- net.sf.ehcache:ehcache-core:jar:2.3.1:compile
[INFO] +- net.sf.ehcache:ehcache-web:jar:2.0.3:compile
[INFO] +- opensymphony:sitemesh:jar:2.4.2:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.commons:commons-io:jar:1.3.2:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs:jar:2.3.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-api:jar:2.3.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.neethi:neethi:jar:2.0.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- wsdl4j:wsdl4j:jar:1.6.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.cxf:cxf-common-schemas:jar:2.3.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-core:jar:2.3.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-impl:jar:2.1.13:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-javamail_1.4_spec:jar:1.7.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- javax.ws.rs:jsr311-api:jar:1.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-bindings-xml:jar:2.3.3:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.codehaus.jettison:jettison:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-common-utilities:jar:2.3.3:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.ws.commons.schema:XmlSchema:jar:1.4.7:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-transports-http:jar:2.3.3:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-transports-common:jar:2.3.3:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws:jar:2.3.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- xml-resolver:xml-resolver:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- asm:asm:jar:3.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-bindings-soap:jar:2.3.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-tools-common:jar:2.3.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-databinding-jaxb:jar:2.3.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-frontend-simple:jar:2.3.3:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-ws-addr:jar:2.3.3:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.ibatis:ibatis-sqlmap:jar:2.3.4.726:compile
[INFO] +- org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:jar:1.6.10:compile
[INFO] +- org.aspectj:aspectjrt:jar:1.6.10:compile
[INFO] +- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-jaxrs:jar:1.7.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-core-asl:jar:1.7.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:jar:1.7.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.codehaus.woodstox:woodstox-core-asl:jar:4.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- javax.xml.stream:stax-api:jar:1.0-2:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.codehaus.woodstox:stax2-api:jar:3.1.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.hibernate.java-persistence:jpa-api:jar:2.0-cr-1:compile
[INFO] +- org.jmock:jmock:jar:2.5.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.6.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.6.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:jar:1.6.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:3.0.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-asm:jar:3.0.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:3.0.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:3.0.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:3.0.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:3.0.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-orm:jar:3.0.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-aspects:jar:3.0.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:3.0.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-test:jar:3.0.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-context-support:jar:3.0.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:3.0.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:3.0.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:3.0.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:jar:3.0.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-config:jar:3.0.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-taglibs:jar:3.0.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:jar:3.0.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework.security:spring-security-acl:jar:3.0.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springmodules:spring-modules-validation:jar:0.8:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-validator:commons-validator:jar:1.3.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- oro:oro:jar:2.0.8:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-digester:commons-digester:jar:1.7:compile
[INFO] |  +- antlr:antlr:jar:2.7.6:compile
[INFO] |  \- rhino:js:jar:1.6R2:compile
[INFO] +- struts-menu:struts-menu:jar:2.4.3:compile
[INFO] |  \- velocity-tools:velocity-tools-view:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] +- taglibs:standard:jar:1.1.2:compile
[INFO] +- velocity:velocity:jar:1.4:compile
[INFO] |  \- velocity:velocity-dep:jar:1.4:runtime
[INFO] +- org.apache.poi:poi:jar:3.10-FINAL:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml:jar:3.10-FINAL:compile
[INFO] |  \- dom4j:dom4j:jar:1.6.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml-schemas:jar:3.10-FINAL:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.xmlbeans:xmlbeans:jar:2.3.0:compile
[INFO] |     \- stax:stax-api:jar:1.0.1:compile
[INFO] +- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.6:compile
[INFO] +- cglib:cglib-nodep:jar:2.2:compile
[INFO] \- com.googlecode.htmlcompressor:htmlcompressor:jar:1.5.2:compile
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESSFUL
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Appreciate any help/insight.

Comment: Solved - conflict in the cxf-servlet.xml file.